# ArcGIS 10.0, Field Calculator Nested "if" statement with strings

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, unicode

I need to assign a value depending on other two columns "FNP" and "Teilort". I wrote this script in phyton for field calculator. It actually works (no error messages) but the results in every cell is 99.

I checked the two columns "FNP" and "Teilort" and the problem doesn't look like to com e from there (no extra blank or white spaces).

What can be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Apparently RefName never equals your comparison strings. All constant strings includes German characters ä or ü, but you don't use the "u" constant string prefix. Depending on the incoming string's format the comparison might not be what you expekt.

You should write 
if RefName==u"Flächen für die Landwirdshaft"
and make sure that RefName also is a correct formatted unicode string.

EDIT:
Do some print of RefName-column of your dataset in a python window in ArcMap to see how the strings look like.

Add the dataset to the map and select a row with RefName="Flächen für die Landwirdshaft"

type the following rows in the pyton window (replace names with your actual names):

```
curs=arcpy.SearchCursor("<name of layer>")
feat=curs.next()
feat.getValue("<name of column for RefName>")
```

The last row will probably print out something like u'Fl\xe4chen ...', which means you have a valid unicode string to compare against. Also try print feat.getValue("") to see that it prints like the literal you are comparing with. Note that the == operator is case sensitive.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Just a question: RefName==u"Flächen für die Landwirdshaft" what does change with the "u" before the string? In this way are recognized also ü, ä, ö?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't improve with the "u": the result is always 99. What do you mean with "correct formatted unicode string", the two coloumns are type "text" and 50 charachters, are there more options?

Comment: The u denotes that the string literal should be interpreted as an unicode string, which is necessary as it contains german letters. Read more on https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html